# Numpy index nested array with indices from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array like:

```
u = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2)

array([[0, 1],
   [2, 3],
   [4, 5],
   [6, 7],
   [8, 9]])
```

I have a second array like

```
a = np.array([1,0,0,1,0])
```

I would like to use the values from a to index the subarrays of u. 
`E.g. a[0] is 1, so we chose u[0,1], a[1] is 0, so we choose u[1, 0]` and so forth.

I have tried lots of things, and would like to do it without for loops. Even after reading [numpys indexing guide](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html) I have not really found how to do it.

Things that I have tried that failed:

```
>>> u[:, [0,0,1,0,1]]
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
   [2, 2, 3, 2, 3],
   [4, 4, 5, 4, 5],
   [6, 6, 7, 6, 7],
   [8, 8, 9, 8, 9]])

u[[True, False, True, True, True]]
array([[0, 1],
   [4, 5],
   [6, 7],
   [8, 9]])
```

Lastly to clear up confusions, here is what I want, however with python loops:

```
>>> x = []
>>> ct = 0
>>> for i in u:
        x.append(i[a[ct]])
        ct += 1

>>> x
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: [1, 2, 4, 7, 8] for the given u and a

Comment: dictionaries are your friends. There are many flavors of it. I would like to recommend the use of panda (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-to_dict/). Just study it once, and your life will be better everytime you need a feature like it.

Comment: @Leos313 I strongly believe that an elegant numpy solution is possible to my problem, so I would like to avoid using pandas and dictionaries.

Comment: @charel-f, completely agree! However, why reinvent the wheels?

Comment: Thats true, but as you can see, the answer by @Dani Mesejo provides a very easy and intuitive solution, which seems more attractive to me than using pandas dataframes inside some algorithm of my project that does not even use pandas at all. Thanks however for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
import numpy as np

u = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2)
a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
r, _ = u.shape  # get how many rows to use in np.arange(r)

print(u[np.arange(r), a])
```

**Output**

```
[1 2 4 7 8]
```

For more on indexing, you can read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and also this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-indexing-explained-c376abb2440d) could be helpful.

Comment: Nice! So its essentially u[[0,1,2,3,4],[1,0,0,1,0]]. If I may ask, what would you call this type of indexing? I.e. where can I find more information about this in the numpy documentation?

Comment: @charel-f it's called advanced indexing.